# Make back button press not canceling actionMode

Tags: java, android

I use start**Support**ActionMode(...) to start acion mode in my app. But when I click on back button on my smartphone, the action mode is canceled.

**I discovered this solution but it doesn't works for me.** The second "if" is not true because when the action mod is working and I press back button, event.getAction() can be only KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN. When action mod is turned off, event.getAction() can be either KeyEvent.ACTION_UP or KeyEvent.ACTION_UP (that I need). And I don't know why it doesn't work

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(mFileExplorerFragment.mActionModeActive){
        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
            //event.getAction() is never == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP 
            //when action mode is working
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing `AppCompatActivity` with `Activity`. I don't know why but it doesn't read `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP` with `AppCompatActivity` while actionMode. But in `Activity` it reads and this really works